# Disable recursive hook calling in Loopback 3

Tags: loopbackjs, loopback

I want to implement computed property. For example, I have `Shop` and `Book` models, `Shop` has many `Books`. And I want create property `booksCost` for `Shop` which equals sum of books price (but I don't want to include all books to query)

My first idea was creating an operation hook

```js
Shop.observe('loaded', async function(ctx) {
    const shopInstanse = ctx.data;
    const books = await Shop.findById(shopInstanse.id).toJSON().books;
    shopInstanse.booksCost = books.reduce((s, book) => s + book.price, 0);
});
```

And I like this way, but when I call `findById`, my hook is called recursively. How to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem using context options

```js
Shop.observe('loaded', async function(ctx) {
    if (ctx.options && ctx.options.skipNextHook) return;
    const shopInstanse = ctx.data;
    const books = (await Shop.findById(shopInstanse.id, {skipNextHook: true}))
        .toJSON().books;
    shopInstanse.booksCost = books.reduce((s, book) => s + book.price, 0);
});
```